# Why is JQ treating arrays as a single field in CSV output?

Tags: json, jq

With the following input file:

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "mydata": {
        "id": "123456",
        "account": "21234"
      }
    },
    {
      "mydata": {
        "id": "123457",
        "account": "21234"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When I run it through this JQ filter,

`jq ".events[] | [.mydata.id, .mydata.account]"  events.json`

I get a set of arrays:

```
[
  "123456",
  "21234"
]
[
  "123457",
  "21234"
]
```

When I put this output through the @csv filter to create CSV output:

`jq ".events[] | [.mydata.id, .mydata.account] | @csv"  events.json`

I get a CSV file with one record per row:

```
"\"123456\",\"21234\""
"\"123457\",\"21234\""
```

I would like CSV file with two records per row, like this:

```
"123456","21234"
"123457","21234"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the -r flag.

Here is the explanation in [the manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Invokingjq):

> `--raw-output / -r`: With this option, if the filter's result is a string then it will be written directly to standard output rather than
>   being formatted as a JSON string with quotes.

```
jq -r '.events[] | [.mydata.id, .mydata.account] | @csv'
```

Yields

```
"123456","21234"
"123457","21234"
```